# Rename docker-compose project without deleting volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to rename a docker-compose project (i.e by renaming the directory or adding `-p new_name` to docker-compose). If I do so I'll remove all my old containers and also all my old volumes. Is there a way to keep the volumes and attach them to the new docker-compose container?

Example `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  dashboard:
    build: custom_dashboard
    volumes:
      - dashboard:/var/lib/grafana
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
volumes:
  dashboard:
```

The project name (and the directory name) was `web` and I want to change it to `grafana`. The Volume name was `web_dashboard` and will be `grafana_dashboard`.

I may could do it manually but I have a very huge docker-compose (but [modularized](https://blog.software-craftsmen.at/blog/2017/docker-compose-best-practices-1.html)) file with about 30 applications.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: unfortunately no, had to do it manually...

Answer (score 20):

Try this work-around:

- Create a copy of the volume with the new name using the script:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  #Author: Guido Diepen

  #Convenience script that can help me to easily create a clone of a given
  #data volume. The script is mainly useful if you are using named volumes


  #First check if the user provided all needed arguments
  if [ "$1" = "" ]
  then
          echo "Please provide a source volume name"
          exit
  fi

  if [ "$2" = "" ] 
  then
          echo "Please provide a destination volume name"
          exit
  fi


  #Check if the source volume name does exist
  docker volume inspect $1 > /dev/null 2>&1
  if [ "$?" != "0" ]
  then
          echo "The source volume \"$1\" does not exist"
          exit
  fi

  #Now check if the destinatin volume name does not yet exist
  docker volume inspect $2 > /dev/null 2>&1

  if [ "$?" = "0" ]
  then
          echo "The destination volume \"$2\" already exists"
          exit
  fi



  echo "Creating destination volume \"$2\"..."
  docker volume create --name $2  
  echo "Copying data from source volume \"$1\" to destination volume \"$2\"..."
  docker run --rm \
             -i \
             -t \
             -v $1:/from \
             -v $2:/to \
             alpine ash -c "cd /from ; cp -av . /to"
  ```
- Delete the previous volume

Credit for the script goes to gdiepen , project: https://github.com/gdiepen/docker-convenience-scripts

Comment: That is truly awesome! Thanks!

Comment: This is working fine, and very helpful

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be no way without renaming the volumes. This worked for me and was actually the fastest way:

> I ended up with creating a new volume and moving manually the content of /var/lib/docker/volumes/old-volume/_data/

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31154#issuecomment-334844525

Answer (score 1):

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  dashboard:
    build: custom_dashboard
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
    volumes:
      - dashboard:/var/lib/grafana
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - CONTAINER_NAME
volumes:
  dashboard:
```

Set `container_name` in your service like above. Then you have to pass the new project name to `container_name` through an env variable and the old project name to the `-p` parameter to keep the old volume with new container's name and new project name.
E.g `mv old_project new_project` and `CONTAINER_NAME=new_project docker-compose -p old_project up -d`.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING**: I presume this flow is not supported, but it fixed this problem for me in 10 seconds...

1. Rename volume references in Docker compose file

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
services:
  my_service:
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: <renamed_volume>
        target: /app
volumes:
  <renamed_volume>:
    external: true
```

2. Locate the volume directory and rename the volume folder

On Windows in WSL the volumes are at:

```
\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\<renamed_volume>
```

On Linux the volumes are at:

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/<renamed_volume>
```

3. Rename the volume in the options file within this directory

`volumes/<renamed_volume>/opts.json`

```
...,"MountDevice":"/path/to/project/<renamed_volume>",...
```

4. Restart Docker